# Add Cell Padding in open xml

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

[image]

I need to add cell padding. Is it possible to do so? It should be similar to the table header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use cell margins.

```
<w:tblPr>
<w:tblCellMar>
<w:top w:w="20" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:start w:w="20" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:bottom w:w="20" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:end w:w="20" w:type="dxa"/>
</w:tblCellMar>
</w:tblPr>
```

see [this link](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellMargins.php) for reference.

Comment: table header and footer are already are separate template .So I added the row dynamically.its not possible to add in my code.can u please tell properties. i added a width like this "TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2400" })".is it any properties for cell padding like above .

Comment: TableCellMargin is the property for cellpadding. see this link for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablecellmargin(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: any further problem?

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: then why you not mark it as answer?